# syntax error, unexpected '$path' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xamppp\htdocs\ecommerce\include\function.php on line 39

Tags: php

This is the line of code that I'm having a problem on

```
function __autoload($class_name){
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
                
}
```

Comment: The syntax looks correct. What line is 39?

Comment: This is line 39

$path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";

Comment: I'm having issue with the __autoload earlier but now It's all good, but the problem is this line 39 now, I'm a newbie on coding btw so please bear with me. This is a project for my FInals

Comment: isn’t  `__autoload()` deprecated?

Comment: As I said, then syntax looks correct, so you most likely have some hidden characters on lines 38 and 39. Delete both lines and retype them.

Comment: I use older version of xampp that supports PHP 5+